# Finding molecules that you randomly create using a modeling kit

Tags: atoms, molecules

I recently bought https://snatoms.com/ (which is just a real-life modeling kit for atoms/molecules) and was just keen on learning about chemistry in general. I often randomly join atoms to make up some molecule. Was wondering if there is an easy way to find the molecule i created?

Comment: A molecule obtained by joining random atoms from a modeling kit is most likely a nonsense and not worth looking up. That being said, you may start from searching by the molecular formula.

Comment: Meantime, you may sign in with [Reaxys](https://www.reaxys.com) and  draw your structures and search for molecules or reactions.

Comment: As far as I know, databases such as Reaxys or SciFinder require institutional access, which OP may or may not have

Comment: @IvanNeretin the kit is mostly carbon, hydrogen, and oxygen, so as long as they use the model correctly, it's not likely they would make something that doesn't exist.

Comment: Chemspider allows a user to input a structure and tries to find a match, you could give that a try

Comment: Just curious, why dont folks add answers instead of comments. That way i could pick the most helpful suggestion/answer as the answer.

Comment: You can apply the rules of the IUPAC nomenclature of organic chemistry to construct the name of the compound you've created. Albeit you might find this way being not too easy, it will give you the maximum insight to chemistry you can expect from playing this kind of game. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IUPAC_nomenclature_of_organic_chemistry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Here's a list of all the stuff you can try:**

For you, the common theme of all these steps would be to be able to correctly identify the skeleton of the molecule that you built yourself, and then being able to draw it on the online molecular editor.

1. Sign into [**Reaxys**](https://www.reaxys.com/) or [**SciFinder**](https://www.cas.org/products/scifinder), draw your structure, and search for molecules or reactions. Note that these require institutional access (or a very hefty fee).
2. **[ChemSpider Structure search:](http://www.chemspider.com/StructureSearch.aspx)** It's a free tool, and my personal goto for getting access to several matching compounds. You can search for "exact matches", or partial matches like "tautomers", "same skeleton", or even "all isomers". There's search filters as well. But again, the first few options are sufficient for your snatoms kit.
3. [**eMolecules**](https://www.emolecules.com/) (in case you didn't notice, we also [advertise it](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4097#4105) in our right sidebar) very similar to ChemSpider above.
4. [**PubChem Structure search**](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/search/search.cgi) - again, similar to the above two. Note that though this one has an odd (and old-looking UI) which you might not find intuitive.

The main difference between all four of these is primarily the level of detail and depth of their data. Functionally, they all do the same thing. But, they do so on *different* *databases*. That means for more complex molecules, their outputs may differ. However, this hopefully won't be a problem with your simple snatoms kit, so you can go ahead and try any of them. Good luck!

---

**Addendum: generating a 3D structure from the molecule name**

You may use this free online [tool](http://biomodel.uah.es/en/DIY/JSME_old/draw.en.htm) based on JSMol. Type the IUPAC name of the molecule (say (1-methylcyclobutyl)benzene) into the lower right box, and press Enter. Its 3D structure is then immediately transferred into the box above. You can zoom it in or out, or rotate it by 360deg. This would help when you're trying to create the 3D molecular structure given the IUPAC name.